# ZipArchiveEx class not found using laravel 4

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have laravel4 setup in local pc with php version 5.5.6.  In Laravel setup i installed the 'codeless/ziparchiveex' module and installed fine but when i put ziparchive coding in my controllers it gives error message "ZipArchiveEx Class Not Found". I see phpinfo file and zip file extension already enable so please help me to solve this issue.

My Coding of controller file is :

```
$zip = new ZipArchiveEx();
                $zip->open('path-to-zip', ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);
                $zip->addDir('directory-path');
                $zip->addDirContents("Image path contents");
                $zip->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you installed the package through composer, did you then registered the package in your `app/cofig/app.php` under the providers and facades arrays?

Otherwise try to require the class on the top of your controllers:

```
require('vendor/codeless/src/ZipArchiveEx.php'); //for the path here just use your installation path
```

Also if you get a:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchiveEx' not found in project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/something/ZipArchiveEx.php on line xyz
```

This should fix it - Go in terminal, navigate to your project's directory and run:

```
composer dump-auto
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This issue is solved using declare a class in app.php file. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi @RameshVadaliya if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.